# HERE API maps geocoding response event

Tags: javascript, maps

I want to expand onResponse callback from geocoding method.

API provide smth like this:

```
geocoder.geocode(geocodingParamsStart, onResult, function(e) {
            alert(e);
        });

function onResult(result) { ... }
```

How can I expand this onResult callback with another arguments?

```
function onResult(result, arg1, arg2, arg3) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to do as below:

```
geocoder.geocode(geocodingParamsStart, 
    function(result) {
        // arg1, arg2, arg3 accessible in this context
        onResult(result, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    },
    function(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
);

function onResult(result, arg1, arg2, arg3) { ... }
```